# How to calculate mean average color in GIMP?

Tags: graphics, photo, gimp

How to calculate mean average color in GIMP?

I have some photo and want to calculate average color - how can I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Find the `Histogram` dockable. It includes a mean, standard deviation, and median for each channel from your image.

Comment: I open the histogram dockable and it says "Mean: 0.788".  Not sure what this means

Answer (score 1):

Use the mean value and times each one by 100 and that should give you individual RGB values. combine them in the colour picker and you should have the average visual colour. Make sure at the top of the colour selection box you select 0..100.
You can do it with the 0..255 box - you just have to times the mean values by 255.